# aggregate calculation vmap jax

Tags: python, numpy, jax

I'm trying to implement fast routine to calculate array of energies and find the smallest calculated value and its index. Here is my code that is working fine:

```py
@jit
def findMinEnergy(x):
  def calcEnergy(a):
    return a*a  # very simplified body, it is actually 15 lines of code
  energies = vmap(calcEnergy, in_axes=(0))(x)
  idx = energies.argmin(axis=0)
  minenrgy = energies[idx]
  return idx, minenrgy
```

I wonder if it is possible to not use the (separate) argmin call, but return the min calculated energy value and it's index from the vmap (similar like other aggregate functions work, e.g. jax.sum)? I hope that it could be more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you JIT-compile your current approach, you should find that it's as efficient as doing something more sophisticated.

Looking at the implementation of `argmin`, you'll see that it computes both the value and the index before returning only the index: https://github.com/google/jax/blob/jax-v0.4.18/jax/_src/lax/lax.py#L3892-L3914

If you want, you could follow this implementation and define a function using `lax.reduce` that returns both these values in a single pass:

```py
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

@jax.jit
def min_and_argmin_onepass(x):
  # This only works for 1D float arrays, but you could generalize it.
  assert x.ndim == 1
  assert jnp.issubdtype(x.dtype, jnp.floating)
  def reducer(op_val_index, acc_val_index):
    op_val, op_index = op_val_index
    acc_val, acc_index = acc_val_index
    pick_op_val = (op_val < acc_val) | jnp.isnan(op_val)
    pick_op_index = pick_op_val | ((op_val == acc_val) & (op_index < acc_index))
    return (jnp.where(pick_op_val, op_val, acc_val),
            jnp.where(pick_op_index, op_index, acc_index))
  indices = jnp.arange(len(x))
  return jax.lax.reduce((x, indices), (jnp.inf, 0), reducer, (0,))
```

Testing this, we see it matches the output of the less sophisticated approach:

```py
@jax.jit
def min_and_argmin(x):
  i = jnp.argmin(x)
  return x[i], i

x = jax.random.uniform(jax.random.key(0), (1000000,))
print(min_and_argmin_onepass(x))
# (Array(9.536743e-07, dtype=float32), Array(24430, dtype=int32))
print(min_and_argmin(x))
# (Array(9.536743e-07, dtype=float32), Array(24430, dtype=int32))
```

If you compare the runtime of the two, you'll see comparable runtimes:

```py
%timeit jax.block_until_ready(min_and_argmin_onepass(x))
# 2.17 ms ± 68.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit jax.block_until_ready(min_and_argmin(x))
# 2.07 ms ± 66.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

The `jax.jit` decorator here means that the compiler optimizes the sequence of operations in the less sophisticated approach, and the result is that you don't gain much advantage from trying to express things more cleverly. Given this, I think your best option is to stick with your original code rather than trying to out-optimize the XLA compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by efficient you mean not having to keep a large array (`energies`) in memory, you can just stack the individual values of `idx` and `minenergy` into a single array within `calcEnergy` and return a (2,) array to `vmap` instead of an (N,) array. It's not pretty as you'll (presumably) have to cast both values to the same `dtype`, but it should work fine.